# Any way to send multipart formdata (POST) to multipart formdata (GET)

Tags: security, post, get, request, multipartform-data

Is there any way to send multipart form data using GET request?

For Example : Can we convert something like below?
`<form action="/action_page_binary.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>`

to

`<form action="/action_page_binary.asp" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>`

Can we do like this? If not, do we have any alternative in terms of sending multipart formdata into GET request?

I need this because there is functionality to upload a file but POST method is not supported by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this for two practical reasons:

1. Browsers will automatically use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for forms that have the `method` attribute set to `GET`.
2. Most servers will disregard the body of any `GET` requests (even though technically adding a body to a get request [is not a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body))